# Can't push object into another object, how can I change my code to work with async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, promise, axios

I'm having issues trying to work with api "pagination", I need to merge multiple objects into one. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this with promises and I'm not sure how to work with async/await to get the best results.

I have a class called selly, which works with the Selly API.

```
getAllProducts(page = 1) {
    return this.makeRequest('products', { page: page });
}
makeRequest(endpoint, params = {}) {
    return axios
        .get(`https://selly.gg/api/v2/${endpoint}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Basic ${this.genApiToken(this.apiKey, this.apiEmail)}`,
                'User-Agent': `username - localhost`,
            },
            params: params,
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Which worked great, until I realized I need to fetch multiple pages and combine all of the results into a single object. Here's my attempt:

```
app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    selly.getAllProducts().then((request) => {
        const pages = request.headers['x-total-pages'];
        let products = request.data;
        if (pages > 1) {
            let i = 2;
            while (pages >= i) {
                selly.getAllProducts(i).then((nextPageRequest) => {
                    nextPageRequest.data.forEach((item) => {
                        products.push(item);
                    });
                });
                i++;
            }
        }
        res.send(JSON.stringify(products));
    });
});
```

I can't seem to push `nextPageRequest` to `products` object. Obviously because `res.send` runs before the promise `selly.getAllProducts(i)` is finished.

I understand that the best optimization for this is using async and await, however I just can't get the basic concept of it, or well, at-least how would I refactor my code into using async and await.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Do you want the requests for the multiple pages to go out in parallel (all at once), or in serial (one only after the last is complete)?

Comment: you actually are pushing in to `products` - it's just that you are also "using" `products` before you've pushed anything on to it - that's asynchrony at work

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'd like to group multiple pages into one then send it out.

Comment: But do you want to send the requests in parallel or in serial?

Comment: One only after the last is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the whole `app.get` handler `async`, then `await` the inital request to figure out how many pages there are, then use a `for` loop and `await` additional calls of `selly.getAllProducts`, pushing the result to the `products` array. Make sure to `try/catch` so you can handle errors:

```
app.get('/api/products', async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  try {
    const request = await selly.getAllProducts();
    const pages = request.headers['x-total-pages'];
    const products = request.data;
    for (let i = 2; i <= pages; i++) {
      const { data } = await selly.getAllProducts(i);
      products.push(...data);
    }
    res.send(JSON.stringify(products));
  } catch(e) {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

Comment: Cool stuff here. I know this is a lot to ask for, but is it possible you can explain, or link to me guides how work with async and where to use it? Feels like every time I attempt to use these keywords, I'm doing it wrong. Love this though, thank you.

Comment: You can make any function `async`, and it will return a `Promise`. This will allow you to use `await` inside - then, anywhere inside the function you're using `<somePromise>.then((result) => {` you can replace that with `const result = await <somePromise>`. Note that `await` isn't *necessary* - it's pretty simple to do the above with only Promises without `async`/`await`, `await` just makes the code flatter and a bit easier to read. See https://javascript.info/async-await