# What are the practical applications of flattening arrays?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, flatten

Why would one need to flatten an array in a real world context?

I've been given this problem in various settings. I searched online but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
   let flat = [];
   for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      let toFlatten = arr[i];
      let element = toFlatten;
      if(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ){
        element = steamrollArray(toFlatten);
      }
      flat = flat.concat(element);
   }
  return flat;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this question?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5barrays%5d%20flatten for many posts where flattening was a problem or a solution, eg flattening was used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992630/cant-push-object-into-another-object-how-can-i-change-my-code-to-work-with-asy/53992662#53992662) only an hour ago

Comment: I got posed this challenge in a job interview, so I was just wondering why flattening an array might be useful.

Comment: Can't think of any time that I've needed it, but the understanding of recursion that it requires is always useful.

Comment: @lisa maybe it can be used to debug print stuff when working on trees?

Comment: There are some recursive solutions to problems that are most simply solved by building a "tree" of arrays and then flattening the whole thing at the end.

Comment: Well if you had an array like `[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 9]]]]` you can easily find if the number `7` is in the array if you flatten it first to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: In the "days of batch", we often had to write various kinds of structured data to linear media, e.g. tape.  Of course you would tend to lose the structure, but something like FBP's brackets could be used to capture the structure, so that it can be recreated when reading the tape...

Comment: @Lisa FWIW, sometimes interview questions/challenges aren't about solving real world problems, it's about seeing how you reason about, explain, and think about problem solving.

Comment: If the original array represents a tree, then this is essentially a breadth-first traversal of the tree. And breadth-first search is a very common technique to solve tree-based problems.

Comment: Single-level flattening of arrays happens every day. The recursive case is rather exotic (except for learning) and you hardly will find arbitrarily-nested arrays in real world data. In a tree, normally each level is wrapped in a node object that stores additional metadata.

Comment: To add a bit on @Bergi's comment, I would even advise against using the recursive variant in real word, If you happen to have a circular reference somewhere, you'll crash your script. Better know your data structure, and call your flattener just as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Two real-world applications of list-flatten used in open-source code I contribute to:

(1) A mapping where some of the resulting elements may be undefined or null and we don't want them in the list. By using flatMap, we can return those elements as empty lists and they won't be included (kind of like a reduce for lazy people :).

```
// As an example,
// list only the odd numbers
console.log(
  steamrollArray(
    [1,2,3].map(e => e & 1 ? e : [])));
```

(2) we have data in this format:

```
{key: value, key: value ...}
```

where each value is a list, and somewhere we need to use the combined list of all the elements in each `value`.

```
var a = {key1: [1, 2], key2: [3, 4]}

console.log(
  steamrollArray(Object.values(a)));
```